# Отправка писем через PHPMailer - от кого

Tags: phpmailer

Добрый день.
Начал пользоваться библиотекой https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
Но вот не пойму, можно ли как-то изменить email отправителя?

```
$mail->Username = 'my-mail@gmail.com';
$mail->setFrom('admin@site.com', 'Admin');
```

На почту приходит письмо от  Admin.
Как изменить email отправителя?

Или мне просто нужно создать корпоративную почту?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Так в поле $mail->setFrom('admin@site.com', 'Admin'); у вас указан отправитель. Там же  Вы его и меняете

Comment: Так вот именно что указан такой, а приходит от my-mail@gmail.com

Comment: А если в пришедшем письме нажать Ответить, то чей адрес будет кому ответ откроется для написания?

Comment: Часто, в целях антиспама,  smtp сервер требует чтобы отправитель был тот же что и login, если они не совпадают, гугл просто его исправляет на логин. Попробуйте другой почтовый сервер

Comment: @Visman кому ответить я могу поставить, но видно что письмо с обычного ящика, а почтовый домен от gmail не бесплатный.

Comment: @Владимир: что-то вы себе противоречите. В вопросе пишите что приходит от Admin. В комментариях пишите, что приходит от my-maiil@gmail.com. Если вам надо поменять имя отправителя - первый комментарий верен. Если  надо поменять адрес для ответа - то ответ есть по приведёной вами же ссылке: `$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');`.

Answer (score 1):

[**Вот пример**](https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wikis/AdvancedMail.wiki)

Вам нужно использовать `$mail->setFrom('имя@домен.com', 'Имя Фамилия');`, как и сказал  *@Cxucxalo*

Как мы можем видеть в [этом участке](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1076) кода, `SetFrom()` третий параметр говорит, что мы можем разрешить устанавливать тот же **email** отправителю, что и адресату.

```
/**
 * Set the From and FromName properties
 * @param string $address
 * @param string $name
 * @param boolean $auto Whether to also set the Sender address, defaults to true
 * @throws phpmailerException
 * @return boolean
 */
public function SetFrom($address, $name = '', $auto = true) {
....
```